# Does Bootstrap tooltip support track:mouse or similar function?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

Yes or no, does the Bootstrap tooltip have any function for making the tooltip trace the mouse?

Suppose I have to use Qtip2 otherwise.

Comment: Did you read the extensive Bootstrap documentation, or do any research on your own?  The answer is a resounding no.

Answer (score 0):

No. Bootstrap cannot do that.

You can also use jQuery-UI's tooltip, but take care to resolve the name conflict between bootstrap's and jquery-ui.